# CUDA: What reasons could there be for nvcc taking several minutes to compile?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvcc

I have some CUDA code that `nvcc` (well, technically `ptxas`) likes to take upwards of 10 minutes to compile.  While it isn't small, it certainly isn't huge.  (~5000 lines).

The delay seems to come and go between CUDA version updates, but previously it only took a minute or so instead of 10.

When I used the `-v` option, it seemed to get stuck after displaying the following:

```
ptxas --key="09ae2a85bb2d44b6" -arch=sm_13 "/tmp/tmpxft_00002ab1_00000000-2_trip3dgpu_kernel.ptx" -o "/tmp/tmpxft_00002ab1_00000000-9_trip3dgpu_kernel.sm_13.cubin"
```

The kernel does have a fairly large parameter list and a structure with a good number of pointers is passed around, but I do know that there was at least one point in time in which very nearly the exact same code compiled in only a couple seconds.

I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 9.04 if it helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps a bug in the compiler? is the compiler using up a lot of memory and causing the system to thrash?

Comment: Given the problem's nature, I wouldn't be surprised.  Especially since when I compile with --device-emulation it compiles quickly.  Of course, even if it is a bug in the compiler, I'd still like to be able to do something about it.

Comment: What happens if you disable optimization?

Comment: The same problem occurs with optimization disabled.

Comment: What version of the toolkit and driver are you using? The 3.0 beta uses an updated backend.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem - without optimization, compilation failed running out of registers, and with optimizations it took nearly half an hour. My kernel had expressions like

```
t1itern[II(i,j)] = (1.0 - overr) * t1itero[II(i,j)] + overr * (rhs[IJ(i-1,j-1)].rhs1 - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].as  * t1itern[II(i,j - 1)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].ase * t1itero[II(i + 1,j - 1)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].ae  * t1itern[II(i + 1,j)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].ane * t1itero[II(i + 1,j + 1)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].an  * t1itern[II(i,j + 1)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].anw * t1itero[II(i - 1,j + 1)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].aw  * t1itern[II(i - 1,j)] - abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].asw * t1itero[II(i - 1,j - 1)] - rhs[IJ(i-1,j-1)].aads * t2itern[II(i,j - 1)] - rhs[IJ(i-1,j-1)].aadn * t2itern[II(i,j + 1)] - rhs[IJ(i-1,j-1)].aade * t2itern[II(i + 1,j)] - rhs[IJ(i-1,j-1)].aadw * t2itern[II(i - 1,j)] - rhs[IJ(i-1,j-1)].aadc * t2itero[II(i,j)]) / abiter[IJ(i-1,j-1)].ac;
```

and when i rewrote them:

```
tt1 = lrhs.rhs1;
tt1 = tt1 - labiter.as  * t1itern[II(1,j - 1)];
tt1 = tt1 - labiter.ase * t1itern[II(2,j - 1)];
tt1 = tt1 - labiter.ae  * t1itern[II(2,j)];
//etc
```

it significantly reduced compilation time and register usage.

Comment: Interesting.  When you rewrote them did it still fail without optimization?  That is, was you re-writing it like that enough of a hint for only the optimizer being able to save registers, or is the basic compiler able to as well?

Comment: It helped even without optimization. Looks like nvcc has troubles with basic compiler, and optimizator issue is just consequence

Answer (score 0):

You should note that there is a limit on the the size of the parameter list that can be passed to a function, currently 256 bytes (see section B.1.4 of the CUDA Programming Guide). Has the function changed at all?

There is also a limit of 2 million PTX instructions per kernel, but you shouldn't be approaching that ;-)

What version of the toolkit are you using? The 3.0 beta is available if you are a registered developer which is a major update. If you still have the problem you should contact NVIDIA, they will need to be able to reproduce the problem of course.

Comment: I'm aware of the parameter restriction, I've run into that problem before.  (And annoyingly, I don't seem able to get around it by just using structs)  It's unclear to me, however, if that's a factor in the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `-maxrregcount 64` on the compile line helps since it causes the register allocator to spill to lmem earlier